# Calculate to six places of decimals the value of...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Calculate to six places of decimals the value of
>   $$(330 ÷ 49)^4 ÷ \sqrt[3]{22\times 70}$$,
>   given $\log 2, \log 3, \log 7$; also 
>   $\log 11 = 1.0413927$, and $\log 17814.1516 = 4.2507651$

My Attempt:
$$(330 ÷ 49)^4 ÷ \sqrt[3]{22\times 70}$$
Taking log on,
$$4(\log 330 - \log 49) - \log..$$,
Tell me how to continue

Comment: Long story short: all the numbers in the problem can be factored as products of the numbers 2,3,7,11, so you can compute their logarithms using the fact that $\log ab =\log a + \log b$.

Comment: I just mean that instead of explicitly writing out each factorization and showing exactly how the log splits the all up, I’ll just say that it can be done. Now the story is getting much longer than I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand everything that can be expanded:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{330}{49}\right)^4}{\sqrt[3]{22 \cdot 70}}=
\frac{\left(\frac{3\cdot 10\cdot 11}{7^2}\right)^4}{\left(2\cdot 11 \cdot 7 \cdot 10\right)^{1/3}}
$$
take the logarithm (base 10!) of the expression and find
$$4(\log 3 + \log 10 + \log 11 - 2\log 7) - \frac{1}{3}(\log 2 + \log 11 +\log 7 + \log 10)$$
note that $\log10= 1$ so
$$4(\log 3 + 1+ \log 11 - 2\log 7) - \frac{1}{3}(\log 2 + \log 11 + \log 7 + 1)$$
replace the values that you have and you get the result :)

Comment: How did the cube root of $22$ times $70$ become the square root of $22$ divided by $70$?

Comment: sorry my mistake! I've corrected it now (I was copying from my paper notes)